# Xtext customized Outline

Tags: xtext, outline-view

I have a customized Outline for an Xtext-based DSL creating new nodes and a different hierarchical structure in the Outline View. Cross-linking with the editor works fine when you click an Outline node. However, the reverse is not happening. I have two requirements:
1. When I click a semantic element in the editor, the Outline Node should be selected if "cross-linked" button is pressed
2. I want to keep the tree structure "expand-all" as I continue to edit the domain model

any pointers are helpful.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

regarding the expansion

package org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui;

```
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.outline.impl.OutlinePage;

public class MyOutlinePage extends OutlinePage {

    @Override
    protected int getDefaultExpansionLevel() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

}


public class MyDslUiModule extends org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.AbstractMyDslUiModule {
    public MyDslUiModule(AbstractUIPlugin plugin) {
        super(plugin);
    }

    public Class<? extends IContentOutlinePage> bindIContentOutlinePage() {
        return MyOutlinePage.class;
    }
}
```

Regarding the Linking:

```
Debug org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.outline.actions.OutlineWithEditorLinker.selectInTreeView(ISelection)
```

Maybe you don't create the nodes correct. but you have to find out that yourself as well how to fix it